# How can I force a component to be recreated?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using Angular 2 v2.1.1. What I'm attempting to do is have component `PersonComponent` created everytime URL parameter `:type` is modified. Reason for this is I'd like to inject from a factory provider an object that correlates to the type. The idea is what I have a set of tabs that are associated to types of people. Each type of person has it's own component that I generate dynamically.

Here is my route configuration -

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PeopleComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: PersonHomeComponent },
            {
                path: ':type',
                component: PersonComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Currently, I'm subscribing to `ActivatedRoute`'s parameters and building my components from that. However, I think it would make testing easier if my component type was injected.

Another idea that I tried, which works, is using resolve on the `:type` route to set properties on `PersonComponent`.

Please let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Currently not supported https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757#issuecomment-236737846

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea this issue existed.